# Mongodb query performance different from app and from command line

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongodb with mongoose in my app. After I've added 4 mln documents more to the db, users started complaining on performance getting more slowly.

I checked this out and discovered, that from desktop it takes 5.5 seconds to handle a request, but if I make this query from command line or via Robo3T, it takes less than two seconds. Is it okay and how can I optimize this query performance?

Comment: Robo3T is a GUI tool which works differently and command line is different. This is not related with query performance unless you have thousands of records.

Comment: Sure they are different. The question was how comes retrieving the same data from db via Robo3T and via my app is so different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Robo3T embeds the engine that is used by mongo shell but your application does not. So the latency from your application to DB will be high because there are many things that come into picture between your app and db servers like, network, no of connections, processing power, queues etc.,

Comment: That makes sense, thank you